# Payment not found (LiqPay package for C#)

Tags: c#, .net, payment

I have errors using the [LiqPay for C# package](https://github.com/JTOne123/liqpay-dotnet/pkgs/nuget/LiqPay#readme).

Debug: `Create`-working, `Status`-error, payment not found, `Cancel` error (but it cancels the payment, but does not provide information about this payment (it is empty)).

My goal is to (using unique order id's (such as: 1,2,3....300)):

1. Create payments and give a link to the user to pay.
2. Check the status of the payment (successful, waiting for payment, cancelled).
3. Cancel payments.

```
using LiqPay.SDK.Dto;
using LiqPay.SDK;
using LiqPay.SDK.Dto.Enums;
using LiqPay;

string publicKey = «myPublicKey";
string privateKey = «myPrivateKey";
string orderId = "20";

var liqpayClient = new LiqPayClient(publicKey, privateKey);

await Create();
await Status();
await Cancel();
Console.ReadLine();

async Task Create()
{
    var invoiceRequest = new LiqPayRequest
    {
        Email = "example@gmail.com",
        OrderId = orderId,
        Amount = 10,
        Currency = "UAH",
        Action = LiqPayRequestAction.InvoiceSend,
        Language = LiqPayRequestLanguage.EN
    };

    LiqPayResponse response = await liqpayClient.RequestAsync("request", invoiceRequest);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Href + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(response.Status + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(response.OrderId + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorDescription + "\n");
}

async Task Status()
{
    var invoiceRequest = new LiqPayRequest()
    {
        OrderId = orderId,
        Action = LiqPayRequestAction.Status,
    };

    LiqPayResponse response = await liqpayClient.RequestAsync("request", invoiceRequest);

    Console.WriteLine($"{response.OrderId}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.Status}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.ErrorDescription}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.Result}\n");
}

async Task Cancel()
{
    var invoiceRequest = new LiqPayRequest
    {
        OrderId = orderId,
        Action = LiqPayRequestAction.InvoiceCancel,   
    };

    var response = await liqpayClient.RequestAsync("request", invoiceRequest);
    Console.WriteLine($"Canceled:{response.Status}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.ErrorDescription}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"{response.OrderId}\n");
}
```

Tried to add the same `invoiceRequest` parameters as in the `Create` method.

`LiqPayResponse response` is not null, but has empty parameters (even `orderID`).